# multi part stream request to .NET Framework 4.5 fails over HTTP, but not local

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

What could cause the following failure when deployed, but not on local?

input: multi-part post of JSON and an MS Word Document.
Output: URIs of processed documents;1. adds header/footer 2. converts to PDF 3. Creates cover sheet from JSON Metadata.
Works: HTTP Long documents without images, up to 300 pages and over 200kb.
Works: .NET app running localhost, up to 500 pages with images.
**Fails: HTTP any document with images over 4 pages.**

MaxRequestLength and most of `Web.config` are defaults.

Running on Azure App Services with the very powerful machine.

App was originally developed to run on a Windows VM and InterOp with Microsoft Office.

It was refactored to run as a standalone .NET app on App Service in order to set up modern CI/CD pipeline.

Requests times out from client.

Wrapping the code in locks slows it down, but doesn't seem to help.

```
maxRequestLength is set to the default.
```

Thanks,

Breakpoint in code reveals the following.
[image]

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> AppendCoverSheet()
    {

        var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

        await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

        var docFileContent = provider.Contents[0];
        var jsonFileContent = provider.Contents[1];

        var requestDocStream = docFileContent.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        string requestDocFileName = docFileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName.Replace("\"", "");
        string requestDocFileExt = Path.GetExtension(requestDocFileName).Replace(".", "");
        string requestDocFileWithoutExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(requestDocFileName);

        var requestJson = jsonFileContent.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentWithCoversheetData>(requestJson);
```

Comment: Your title mentions.NET Core, your question mentions .NET Framework, and your code sample is ASP.NET (not sure if Core or not). Which is it?

Comment: @McGuireV10 Framework. Updated. TY

Comment: Is this a direct copy of your real code? If so, you're missing `await` on `ReadAsStreamAsync` and `ReadAsStringAsync` (and you wouldn't need `.Result` after adding await).